# How to use Xamarin Community Toolkit extension properties and attributes in the C# code behind?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-community-toolkit

I am using **Xamarin.Community Toolkit's** `ShadowEffect.Color` and `IconTintColorEffect.TintColor` through XAML and it is working fine, but how can I achieve this through the C# Code Behind. I have searched on Google and Community Forums but could not find anything.

**Here is my code in XAML:**

```xml
<BoxView BackgroundColor="White" xct:ShadowEffect.Color="Black" />
<Image Source="{extensions:ImageResource MyProject.Images.sample.png" xct:IconTintColorEffect.TintColor="Blue" />
```

Everything is working fine in XAML, but I want to achieve this from C# code behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ShadowEffect.SetColor(boxView, Color.Black);

IconTintColorEffect.SetTintColor(image, Color.Blue);
```

Where `boxView` and `image` are instances either from your xaml by using `x:Name` or instantiated in code.